# views exposed filters. get access to user

Tags: views, users

I have a views "simply views" with many nodes. I need to get access to user, if node has link to this user.
For example I have node "custom access" and field "field_link_user" with value "James" (is the link to drupal user James). And when James go to page "simply views" it see only 1 node "custom access".
I'm know, it's doing with expsoed filters in views, but how..